# How do I get 12.04.1 to appear on the update manager

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 12.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179979/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-12-04-1)

I have received the announcement that 12.04.1 LTS has been released today.

I have followed various instructions to upgrade to it, but nowhere does it appear on the Update Manager.

Or has it not actually been released?

Running 12.04 on VMWare Fusion 4.1.3 on Mac OS 10.7.4