# Is it possible to upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 12.04.1?

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade to 12.04.1 from 12.04 LTS. Is it possible? If possible then How?

Comment: @Alvar 12.04.1 came out today http://www.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Type `lsb_release -a` to check, you're probably already in 12.04.1 if you've done all the updates.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to do anything special. Just update your PC either using the Upgrade Manager (how you normally get updates) or use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

There isn't anything special about the point releases, they are just bundled updates. It's more for when you download an iso, so it will have more of the updates already.

Comment: Is it safe? Can something drastically change during upgrade?

Comment: As has been stated, all the point releases are are bundled updates for ISOs. They are just regular updates.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running 12.04 with all the updates you are running 12.04.1

12.04.1 is just a "point release", which adds the updates into the ISO file. You can read about the process [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PointReleaseProcess). It is not a distribution upgrade so you won't see the option to upgrade in update manager.

Answer (score 2):

To verify if you have updated to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. 
Run this command on your Terminal:

cat /etc/issue